# What does Islam think about Islamic swimsuit women wear?

Tags: women, clothing

I have once seen it in Turkey's beaches. Women who had worn it didn't seem comfortable in it and couldn't swim well and were shy. What is the idea of Islam about this cloth?

Comment: Which one? Some of them are practically abayas, whereas some are skintight.

Comment: It was not skintight but my question is to find what Islam says about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [What does Islam say about X?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/what-does-islam-say-about-x) question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Islam encourages its followers to maintain a healthy body through athletic activities. However, under Sharia law, Muslims are required to cover the genitals - which is considered an intimate part of the body that can only be seen by friends or relatives / friends of the same sex.
If he can not swim well not because of his clothing, but because of the lack of ability to swim. Yet for the sake of exercise alone, not for Olympic Games

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq), in it is what you need to know about how things work.  Here, we require answers to contain citation from the Quran, Sunnah, reliable Fatwas, and or from any other reliable/authentic sources.  The question is asking about women in Islamic swimsuits.  Please edit your answer to directly answer the question, and do not forget to add citations/references. We look forward to having you participate here, please look around at other questions and answers to get a feel on how things work here.

Comment: friends are not maharam and not all relatives, try to provide some authrntic references