# What should a Muslim woman look for in a burkini?

Tags: practical-islam, women, clothing

> A burkini... is a type of modesty swimsuit for women... the suit covers the whole body except the face, the hands and the feet, while being light enough for swimming. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burkini)

[image: Image source: Wikimedia commons]

Looking online, there's a range of different burkini styles around.  Some seem to aim to cover the awrah of a woman (in front of men), while some are more practical for swimming (a kind of compromise solution, or perhaps better suited for swimming only with women).

**Question**: What should a Muslim woman look for in a burkini?

There seems to be a bunch of problems with burkinis:

1. They incompletely cover the awrah.
2. They are skin tight, or become so when wet.
3. They inhibit swimming.
4. They are potentially a drowning hazard.

*Edit*: I tried some conservative swimwear I bought in Turkey.  I can confirm 1., 2., and 3.; basically it's like swimming while wearing everyday clothes.  And 4. is a logical conclusion from 3.  From my experience, I can also add:

5. You draw attention to yourself by looking different (assuming not all women are wearing them).
6. They're difficult to change out of when wet.

A related question is here: [What does Islam think about Islamic swimsuit women wear?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7467/17163), but I'm trying to be more specific and practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *awrah* of a woman infront of other women is the area from the navel to the knees:

According to the Hanafi, [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.216460/2015.216460.The-Hedaya#page/n615/mode/2up):

> A woman is permitted to look at any part of another except from under
>   the navel to the knee. This is according to one tradition of Haneefa ;
>   but according to another tradition, the looking of one woman at
>   another of her sex, is the same as that of a man at his female
>   relation: that is, they are not permitted to look at the back or
>   belly. The first tradition is. however, the most authentic.

According to the Shafi, [Minhaj Al-Talibin](https://archive.org/stream/minhaj_al-talibin_english#page/n299/mode/2up):

> Men may look at each other, provided they keep concealed the part of
>   the body between navel and knees ...
>
> Women among themselves should observe the rule laid down for men.

So if you are considering one for a segregated pool or segregated beach anything that at least covers that area would be permissible.

For a beach where there will be both non-mahram men and women, the rules of Hijab will apply ... and there should be a somewhat loose covering over the chest according to [Quran 24:31](https://quran.com/24/31) (the purpose being to blur the breasts, hips and pubic area). I doubt that a mixed gender swimming pool is permissible, indeed conservative fatwas also abhor segregated pools.

Thickness and weight of the cloth does not matter as long as its not see-through.

Answer (score 2):

Look for a burkini that doesn't project (literally and figuratively) the women's beauties.

Additionally one can go and swim in remote areas. That's what most women in my family do. Being a Muslims I've realized that overtime, life will get easier. It's just the first 100 years that are difficult :|
My gag is in direct reference to:

> [From Imam Kadhim:](https://www.al-islam.org/fr/node/28759)
>
> *أَما إِنَّ أَبْدانَكُمْ لَیسَ لَها ثَمَنٌ إِلاَّ الْجَنَّةَ، فَلا تَبیعوها بِغَیرِها...*
>
> ...be aware for your body (yourself) there's no value for it other than paradise, don't ever sell it for anything less!
>
> <sub>al-Kafi, vol. 1, p-19</sub>