# Is swimming in a mixed pool allowed if women are covered?

Tags: halal-haram, hijab, men-women, modesty

I doubt that males are permitted to swim in a pool with women who are wearing a swimsuit or bikini even if they averted their gaze. The environment is haraam. Now what if the women were wearing the Islamic style of swimwear - is such a mixed pool still haraam for Muslim males? It goes back to segregation for the sexes in a pool or outside the pool. Some scholars may say the swimwear is too tight so fails for a suitable hijaab also.

Comment: If Women and men are allowed to visit mosque, perform Haj, visit Eid Gah or do shopping without segregation then I doubt if there could be a problem with them in being in the same swimming pool... Off course conditions apply. The swim suit should not be tight enough and men and women should refrain from touching each-others body, especially the private parts.

There are no hadith's or verses in the Quran that directly instructs women and men be segregated especially at swimming pools. At the time swimming pools never existed but offcourse rivers, lakes and ponds did.

Comment: @qaisarkhan ok but at those times women and men were segregated due to the cultures at those times (even if lakes existed). Even non Muslims would not partake in such activities. What is your point?

Comment: My point is straight. I was unable to find a hadith or verse in the Quran which Instructs women to be segregated from Men especially at swimming places. back then They were allowed to go to battles together, to perform Hajj and umra together and to pray together. The only segregation that is mentioned is that women were allowed to have a separate door to the mosque and were not allowed to pray shoulder to shoulder with men. But thats purely to stop them from distracting men from praying, Which matters. Swimming doesn't matter. But women needs to be covered as per the rules mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this is no different from everyday co-existing, but in water instead of air.  As usual, both men and women would need to cover their awrah.  However, it's practically problematic to do so.  The main issues described by fatawa (below) are "temptation" and "uncovered awrah".

I asked about the women's swimwear here: [What should a Muslim woman look for in a burkini?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38920/17163)  I also bought a burkini myself (when I was in Turkey), and tried it on in the pool.  Basically, they're either skin tight, or become skin tight when they get wet (as described at [AboutIslam](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/women-issues/can-muslim-woman-go-public-swimming-pools/)).  They're also very difficult to swim in, to the point where they might be a drowning hazard.  Combining these factors, it seemed rather pointless.

Fatawa are quite strong about this, describing it as a "great evil" ([IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=278059)) and that there are "other un-Islamic or unethical factors" ([AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/17649)).  [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/159926) goes further and says its not even permissible if it were just women.

Answer (score 0):

Is it permissible to cover women in a mixed pool?
It is not permissible to go to swimming pools where men and women are involved, and also to places where men and women are naked, if it leads to haram, but as a precaution, it should be left, even if it does not lead to haram.

Ref: https://rasekhoon.net/faq/show/1151751/%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7